# Create and use a list in an IF statement in SAS

Tags: arrays, list, macros, sas

User PomPazz post this answer for creating a list from input variables:

"You need to use a macro to "write" the SAS code for you.

This should do what you are looking for. It takes a space delimited list of values, and loops over them doing what your code specifies. Post a comment if you have a question on it.

```
%macro doit(list);
proc sql noprint;
%let n=%sysfunc(countw(&list));
    %do i=1 %to &n;
        %let val = %scan(&list,&i);
        create table somlib._&val as
            select * from somlib.somtable
            where item=&val;
    %end;
quit;
%mend;

%doit(100 101 102);
```

Note, data sets cannot start with a number so I have these starting with '_'"

My questions is, how can this be applied to creating a list from a variable in a dataset that can be used in an IF statement such as "IF Telephone in(List) then Invalid=1"

This is needed to validate a list of telephone numbers from a predetermined list of invalid numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic answer to your question is that you need to pull it into a macro variable or an include file.

```
proc sql;
select distinct telephone into :tellist separated by ',' 
from invalid_phones;
quit;


data want;
set have;
if telephone in (&tellist.) then invalid=1;
run;
```

This is limited to about 32k characters, so if you have more than ~3000 phone numbers it may not work.  If telephone is character you need to `select distinct quote(telephone)` instead.

The more detailed answer is that this, usually, is inefficient.  Better is to use a format.

```
data for_fmt;
set invalid_phones;
start=telephone;
label='INVALID';
fmtname='TELCHECKF'; *add $ if telephone is a character field;
output;
if _n_=1 then do;  *this block adds a line to deal with non-matching records (hlo=o means other);
 start=.;
 label='VALID';
 hlo='o';
output;
end;
run;

proc format cntlin=for_fmt;
quit;

data want;
set have;
if put(telephone,TELCHECKF.)='INVALID' then invalidflag=1;
run;
```

This can be faster than the list method, and doesn't have the length issues.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, worked fine using the first method as only a few hundred numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Joe's answer is great, but I just wanted to add that you can do this in one SQL step

```
proc sql noprint;

    create table want as
    select *, case
                when telephone in (select distinct telephone from invalid_phones) then 1
                else 0
            end as invalid
    from have
    ;
quit;
```

Comment: Tried this too and it worked fine, I am only going to stock with Joe's answer as my accepted answer as it creates a macro variable which has proven useful for validating multiple datasets. Thanks very much for responding as well though!

Comment: I tried this. It quickly becomes inefficient as `invalid_phones` has more and more values. Perfectly fine if few invalid numbers.